# iOS15: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer: how to un-share objects?

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I’m working on an app that uses the new sharing support in iOS 15 using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. I do not see a way to tell Core Data that an object, or set of objects, is no longer shared.

For example, if I create a set of objects and then call `share(_:to:completion:)`, the objects are shared properly and moved to a new, custom `CKRecordZone`, as expected.

Now, if the user stops sharing an object using `UICloudSharingController`, the `CKShare` that Core Data created is properly deleted from CloudKit, but the objects are still in the custom zone, and Core Data still has the original `CKShare` associated with those objects. So, when I call `fetchShares(matching:)`, I still get the `CKShare`, but of course, that is no longer valid. In the past, with my own code, I’d use `UISharingController`s delegate to get notified that the user stopped sharing, and then update my model. But there doesn’t seem to be a way to tell Core Data about the change.

Forcing Core Data to fetch CloudKit changes by either moving the app to background and then foreground, or by stopping the app and relaunching does not cause Core Data to notice the change to the share.

Does anyone know how to tell Core Data that these objects are no longer shared?

Comment: filed a feedback with Apple. Hopefully we get some way to do this in the future. In the mean time, I’ve had to implement some work-arounds in my app. I don’t love them, but they work well.

Comment: Did you use `CKModifyRecordsOperation` by chance?

Comment: No, I still use the `UICloudSharingController` to stop sharing. But to check whether a record is shared (so I can update the UI), instead of relying on the presence of a `CKShare` from `fetchShares(matching:)`, I get the share’s url from that method, and call `CKContainer.shareMetadata(for: url)` to verify the share actually exists in CloudKit. I am going to write up more about what I did in hopes of helping others. There are quite a few “gotchas” with the current implementation.

Comment: I ask because it appears from outdated documentation that previously that may have been how it was done? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/shared_records/sharing_cloudkit_data_with_other_icloud_users

Comment: Yes, that is how it’s done if you want to manually remove a share by using your own code. But, the `UICloudSharingController` does this for you when the user chooses “Stop Sharing.”

Comment: I see - I believe the `CKShare` is being intentionally left as a way to propagate the changes to the share participants. (WWDC20 Public Databases) Since the `rootRecordID` is being set to `null`, which I believe is the actual object(s)? So I'm not sure what the right course of action would be.

Answer (score 3):

I worked around this by always checking to see if the share actually exists in CloudKit, rather than relying on the existence of a `CKShare` from `fetchShares(matching:)`.  I get the `URL` from the `CKShare` returned from `fetchShares(matching:)` and call this:

```
private func remoteShare(at url: URL) async throws -> CKShare? {
        do {
            let metadata = try await cloudKitContainer.shareMetadata(for: url)
            return metadata.share
        } catch let error as CKError {
            if error.retryable {
                throw RemoteError.retryable
            } else if error.userInterventionRequiredError {
                throw RemoteError.userInterventionRequired
            } else if error.code == .unknownItem {
                return nil
            } else {
                throw RemoteError.remoteFailure
            }
        } catch {
            throw RemoteError.remoteFailure
        }
    }
}
```

If I get `unknownItem` that means there is no share on the remote, so the object is not actually shared.

The `RemoteError` is my custom error handling, and I have some extensions on `CKError` to categorize the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround to the issue is to create a copy of the object being shared, and then deleting the original. It's not elegant, but it works in the meantime. (Hopefully Apple will address this at some point with a better solution.)
The copy will be placed in the default zone like it was before you shared the original. You'll be left with an empty share zone, but I dealt with that by running a background task upon app launch that deletes all empty share zones, so it doesn't get out of hand.

I haven't tried the solution posted by Dharman, but I imagine it's slower than querying the local cache. Using the method above, you can still use the "isShared" code from the demo app.